# Putting both save button and cancel button in Delivery Address of a Customer through his/her Checkout Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkout

I am planning to put both save and cancel button inside the Update Delivery Address Link Button. What are your suggestions about this problem? How I can fix this problem below??

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Delivery Address(Optional)</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateAddress" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateAddress_Click" Text="Update Address" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" visible="false" runat="server" id="Street2">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Street</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStreet2" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="50" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" visible="false" runat="server" id="Municapility2">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Municipality</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMunicapility2" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="100" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" visible="false" runat="server" id="Region2">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Region</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegion2_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" visible="false" runat="server" id="City2">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">City</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity2" runat="server" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="pull-right">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" class="btn btn-success" Text="Save" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" class="btn btn-danger" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
    </span>
</div>
```

C# Codes for LinkButton of Delivery Add

C# Codes for LinkButton of Delivery Address

```
protected void UpdateAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateAddress.Visible = false;
    Street2.Visible = true;
    City2.Visible = true;
    Region2.Visible = true;
    Municapility2.Visible = true;
}
```

This is the code behind file for Save and Cancel Button for Update Delivery Address.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, " +
        "CityID=@CityID, RegionID=@RegionID, FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", txtStreet.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipality", txtMunicipality.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", ddlCity.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegionID", ddlRegion.SelectedValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("/Accounts/Checkout.aspx");
}
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET Street=@Street, Municipality=@Municipality, " +
        "CityID=@CityID, RegionID=@RegionID, FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", txtStreet.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Municipality", txtMunicipality.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", ddlCity.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegionID", ddlRegion.SelectedValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("/Accounts/Checkout.aspx");
}
```

Visualization of my problem[Hiding of the Buttons in Delivery Address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbTkm.png)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you describe what goes wrong?

Comment: I want to show both the save and cancel button once the linkbutton for delivery address is clicked by the customer in his checkout page. Then is there something wrong with my C# codes?

Comment: Again, what is going wrong? What is the problem? Please put the problem into words...

Comment: I want to hide the those buttons. Once you clicked the update delivery address button, aside from text boxes, there are Save and Cancel buttons will appear on that. My problem on that is how can I hide those buttons in another button. Let's say that the Customer wants to edit his Delivery Address, instead of using his billing address. Once he edited that info, he will click either Save or Cancel. Sorry for my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To start-off with hidden buttons, i think you can use Visible="false"

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSave"   Visible="false" ... />
  <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Visible="false" ... />
```

When you click the Delivery Address button, make them visible:

```
  protected void UpdateAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      btnSave.Visible = true;
      btnCancel.Visible = true;
  }
```

To hide them when another control is clicked:

```
  protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      btnSave.Visible = false;
      btnCancel.Visible = false;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Mr buffjape